# ASP.Net MVC Some CSS and JS in shared layout should not be used in content pages

Tags: css, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to asp.net MVC. I have some views which use the same shared layout page. Now I got a new shared layout page which has its specific design and thus has associated new css and js files.

I understand content pages just inject their markup in the @RenderBody section of shared layout page. But still is there any way we make sure some of css and js should not affect the markup of the child page.

Comment: If you want the css and js not to affect the page content, why do you load them?

Comment: @Programmer Loaded css and js contains the style and functional scripts for master page(sharelayout) only

Comment: can i have an example case of your layout/child inheritance problem?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like what you're saying is that you have CSS that is geared towards your layout page, that is also (undesirably) affecting your views?

As you are correct in saying, @RenderBody just inserts the content from your view into the layout page and what is produced is one whole document. Any CSS or JavaScript is going to affect the entire page. You can however control which elements it affects, which I believe is your problem.

You just need more specific selectors in your CSS.
For example if you have a div in your master page that you wanted a border on:

```
div { border: 1px solid black; }
<div></div>
```

Would be bad, as it would affect every div on the page. Try creating classes and applying them to your elements, e.g.:

```
.div-black-border { border: 1px solid black; }
<div class="div-black-border"></div>
```

The same logic can be applied to your javascript selectors (presuming that's the issue).

Answer (score 0):

Every css rule you write should be scoped towards the least amount of elements. If something at the layout should not affect every children maybe it shouldn't be at the layout.

This is why classes are used to limit the scope & be specific.

To get this a step ahead i usually limit towards a parent container of each page, to make sure if any generic rule is created it won't leak towards all the site.

HTML

```
   <div class="main__container">

   </div>
```

CSS

```
.main__container {
   background: red;
}
```